# PHP / MySQL nth row with DATE_SUB, etc

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a table, I use to graph some data.
id, agcid, ooscount, date

Data is samples every 5 minutes for 18 objects
ID is auto increment, agcid represents the ID of the object, date is self explanitory and ooscount is an integer column.

I'm currently using this:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT ooscount, date 
          FROM ooscount 
          where agcid = '".$agcid."' AND date >= DATE_SUB(NOW( ),INTERVAL 7 HOUR) 
          order by date  DESC";
```

Simple, yet effective, however I have an extremely large dataset which complicates the graphs.

I tried adding AND ooscount.id mod 3 = 0 to this however, the data sets on each agcid seemed very random, some had only a couple, others had 5x more than they should.

I then tried an approach like this:

```
  $sql2 = "set @row:=-1; 
        SELECT ooscount.*
        FROM
            ooscount
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT id
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT @row:=@row+1 AS rownum, id 
                        FROM
                            (
                                SELECT id, date, ooscount FROM ooscount where agcid = '".$agcid."' and date >= DATE_SUB(NOW( ),INTERVAL 12 HOUR) order by date DESC
                            ) AS sorted
                    ) as ranked
                WHERE rownum % 3 = 0
            ) AS subset
                ON subset.id = ooscount.id;";
```

It's commented out, forgive the //'s. However this approach while it works in phpMyAdmin, gives me this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc()
on a non-object in /var/www/khamlin/oosagc.php on line 145
```

Lastly, the portion of code to display this:

```
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
$rowsarray = "";
//var_dump($result2);
while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
```

I believe the problem is that examples I've found don't expect multiple data sets on a single table, and thus ID would be incremental (ie: 1,2,3,4,5,6, etc), rather than ( 168006, 168023, 168041, 168060 ).

How would I go about changing this to suit my needs here?

Structure

`` CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ooscount` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `agcid` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `ooscount` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=168580 ; ``

````

Sample Data: https://jpst.it/1bfFt

Current Output: a data point of ooscount and date every 5 minutes (ie:
`data: [{"ooscount":"4907","date":"2018-02-21 09:40:01"},{"ooscount":"4905","date":"2018-02-21 09:35:02"},{"ooscount":"4910","date":"2018-02-21 09:30:02"},{"ooscount":"4904","date":"2018-02-21 09:25:01"},{"ooscount":"4900","date":"2018-02-21 09:20:02"},{"ooscount":"4898","date":"2018-02-21 09:15:02"},{"ooscount":"4989","date":"2018-02-21 09:10:01"},{"ooscount":"5008","date":"2018-02-21 09:05:02"},{"ooscount":"4933","date":"2018-02-21 09:00:01"},{"ooscount":"4915","date":"2018-02-21 08:55:01"},{"ooscount":"4903","date":"2018-02-21 08:50:02"},{"ooscount":"4898","date":"2018-02-21 08:45:01"},{"ooscount":"4899","date":"2018-02-21 08:40:01"},{"ooscount":"4909","date":"2018-02-21 08:35:01"},{"ooscount":"4918","date":"2018-02-21 08:30:01"},{"ooscount":"4906","date":"2018-02-21 08:25:02"},{"ooscount":"4906","date":"2018-02-21 08:20:01"},{"ooscount":"4900","date":"2018-02-21 08:15:02"},{"ooscount":"4895","date":"2018-02-21 08:10:01"},{"ooscount":"4883","date":"2018-02-21 08:05:02"},{"ooscount":"4881","date":"2018-02-21 08:00:01"},{"ooscount":"4879","date":"2018-02-21 07:55:02"},{"ooscount":"4883","date":"2018-02-21 07:50:02"},{"ooscount":"4875","date":"2018-02-21 07:45:02"},{"ooscount":"4875","date":"2018-02-21 07:40:01"},{"ooscount":"4879","date":"2018-02-21 07:35:02"},{"ooscount":"4882","date":"2018-02-21 07:30:01"},{"ooscount":"4888","date":"2018-02-21 07:25:01"},{"ooscount":"4877","date":"2018-02-21 07:20:01"},{"ooscount":"4879","date":"2018-02-21 07:15:02"},{"ooscount":"4884","date":"2018-02-21 07:10:02"},{"ooscount":"4886","date":"2018-02-21 07:05:02"},{"ooscount":"4904","date":"2018-02-21 07:00:02"},{"ooscount":"4906","date":"2018-02-21 06:55:01"},{"ooscount":"4904","date":"2018-02-21 06:53:32"},{"ooscount":"4904","date":"2018-02-21 06:50:02"},{"ooscount":"4892","date":"2018-02-21 06:45:01"},{"ooscount":"4795","date":"2018-02-21 06:40:02"},{"ooscount":"4793","date":"2018-02-21 06:35:01"},{"ooscount":"4799","date":"2018-02-21 06:30:02"},{"ooscount":"4797","date":"2018-02-21 06:25:02"},{"ooscount":"4802","date":"2018-02-21 06:20:01"},{"ooscount":"4801","date":"2018-02-21 06:15:01"},{"ooscount":"4792","date":"2018-02-21 06:10:02"},{"ooscount":"4798","date":"2018-02-21 06:05:02"},{"ooscount":"4797","date":"2018-02-21 06:00:01"},{"ooscount":"4798","date":"2018-02-21 05:55:02"},{"ooscount":"4794","date":"2018-02-21 05:50:01"},{"ooscount":"4796","date":"2018-02-21 05:45:02"},{"ooscount":"4804","date":"2018-02-21 05:40:02"},{"ooscount":"4803","date":"2018-02-21 05:35:01"},{"ooscount":"4809","date":"2018-02-21 05:30:02"},{"ooscount":"4811","date":"2018-02-21 05:25:01"},{"ooscount":"4810","date":"2018-02-21 05:20:01"},{"ooscount":"4831","date":"2018-02-21 05:15:02"},{"ooscount":"4839","date":"2018-02-21 05:10:02"},{"ooscount":"4859","date":"2018-02-21 05:05:01"},{"ooscount":"4859","date":"2018-02-21 05:00:01"},{"ooscount":"4858","date":"2018-02-21 04:55:02"},{"ooscount":"4858","date":"2018-02-21 04:50:02"},{"ooscount":"4863","date":"2018-02-21 04:45:02"},{"ooscount":"4868","date":"2018-02-21 04:40:01"},{"ooscount":"4872","date":"2018-02-21 04:35:01"},{"ooscount":"4868","date":"2018-02-21 04:30:02"},{"ooscount":"4867","date":"2018-02-21 04:25:02"},{"ooscount":"4870","date":"2018-02-21 04:20:01"},{"ooscount":"4866","date":"2018-02-21 04:15:02"},{"ooscount":"4864","date":"2018-02-21 04:10:02"},{"ooscount":"4863","date":"2018-02-21 04:05:01"},{"ooscount":"4874","date":"2018-02-21 04:00:02"},{"ooscount":"4881","date":"2018-02-21 03:55:01"},{"ooscount":"4850","date":"2018-02-21 03:50:02"},{"ooscount":"4846","date":"2018-02-21 03:45:01"},{"ooscount":"4847","date":"2018-02-21 03:40:02"},{"ooscount":"4850","date":"2018-02-21 03:35:02"},{"ooscount":"4845","date":"2018-02-21 03:30:01"},{"ooscount":"4847","date":"2018-02-21 03:25:02"},{"ooscount":"4848","date":"2018-02-21 03:20:01"},{"ooscount":"4847","date":"2018-02-21 03:15:02"},{"ooscount":"4852","date":"2018-02-21 03:10:03"},{"ooscount":"4854","date":"2018-02-21 03:05:01"},{"ooscount":"4864","date":"2018-02-21 03:00:01"},{"ooscount":"4867","date":"2018-02-21 02:55:02"},{"ooscount":"4868","date":"2018-02-21 02:50:01"},{"ooscount":"4862","date":"2018-02-21 02:45:02"}],`

The goal is to have less data points over the same amount of time.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me.

`$sql2 = "SELECT *
         FROM ( 
               SELECT @row := @row +1 AS rownum, ooscount.*
               FROM (
                     SELECT @row :=0) r, ooscount where agcid='".$agcid."' and date >= DATE_SUB(NOW( ),INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
                     ) ranked
         WHERE rownum %3 =1";`